# Windows Registry Edit, dynamic registry address

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, edit

Every day i have to use the Local Group Policy Editor to configure some computers (windows 10), so I want to create a batch (*.bat) script to do it automatically and quickly.

I manage to write down this script which is working...

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{7DD69AA7-9A2E-4966-A274-9DE9DD62D62B}Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\NoAutoUpdate /v NoAutoUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

My problem is that the script is working only on my machine because on another computer the `7DD69AA7-9A2E-4966-A274-9DE9DD62D62B` code in the register address is different and it's different for every computer.
This code is present also in all other register address that I have to modify.

- What is that code?
- Is there a way to write a generic register address that will work on different machines without the need of changing it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Seems like this should be a machine policy you set in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU`.

Comment: I think you will find that the registry layout under ...\Windows\CurrentVersion changes from version to version of the OS.  Why are you disabling windows update? I seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: `reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion /V NoAutoUpdate /S` should show that code(s) if any…